# Question on もらう

Tags: giving-and-receiving

In my textbook, I was given the following two sentences and was told the meanings did NOT match. (The translations are from what I can understand)

「私はコンサートのチケット、もらってくれませんか。」*"Won't you give me this concert ticket?"*

「私はこのチケットをもらいたい。」*"I want to be given this ticket."*

I don't understand which sentence I am misunderstanding, and why. 私は is the subject, so using もらう would mean that **I** receive the ticket, right? Or is it the を that changes it?

Comment: **私は**コンサートのチケット、もらってくれませんか。 doesn't make sense as is. Can you double-check if you've copied it correctly?

Comment: Your first sentence clearly has some error, and it's hard to explain the grammar of an incorrect sentence. Please use the "Edit" button and fix it first.